# How to access fields inside a model

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I´m using Sencha Touch 2 and have defined a model like this:

```
Ext.define('csx.model.Profile', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

 config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'firstname',type: 'string'},
        {name: 'lastname', type: 'string'},
    ],

    hasMany: [
        {model: 'Telephone', name: 'telephones'},
        {model: 'Email', name: 'emails'},
    ],
 },

 doSomething: function () {
    var firstname = this.get('firstname'); //returns null
    var phones = this.telephones(); // throws a TypeError
},

});
```

Inside my function `doSomething` I am trying to access the values of the model and the  models associated with the `hasMany` property. The `get`function only returns null and when I try to access the associated models I only get a TypeError saying that the object doesn´t have a telephones function. But when I look at the Sencha Touch 2 guides [UsingModels](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/models) on how to use models it says that the `hasMany` associations are accessible trough a function resembling the name I specified (telephones).

So how do I access the field values and the associated models inside a model instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the model properties in the 'hasMany' config of your model to reflect the full name of your models:

```
hasMany: [
    {model: 'csx.model.Telephone', name: 'telephones'},
    {model: 'csx.model.Email', name: 'emails'},
],
```

That is, supposing you have defined your models Telephone and Email like this:

```
Ext.define('csx.model.Telephone', { 
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'number', type: 'string'},
        ],
 });

Ext.define('csx.model.Email', { 
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'address', type: 'string'},
        ],
 });
```

Then, if you create an instance of your 'Profile' model:

```
var profile = Ext.create('csx.model.Profile', {firstname:'John',lastname:'Deere'});
```

you can access your fields like this:

```
profile.get('firstname');
profile.get('lastname');
```

and the 'telephones' and 'emails' stores from the hasMany associations like this:

```
profile.telephones()
profile.emails()
```

The fact that your 'firstname' field had a null value is because you didn't instantiate your model. The fact that the 'telephones()' function was not created automatically as stated in the docs is because of the wrong 'model' configuration as explained in the beginning of this answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I totally got that wrong. Probably I was just to busy copying the docs instead of noticing my errors. I tested it with the right config and it works.